# how to do the calculation in an array

Tags: php

I have an array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
  (
      [batch_id] => 1
      [seq_id] => 1
      [q_id] => 2046
      [a1] => 0
      [a2] => 1
      [a3] => 2
      [a4] => 3
      [a5] => 4

  )
)
```

I need to minus the value of a1-a5 by 1

desire result(e.g. a1):

```
 array(4) {
["w_id"]=>
string(5) "99911"
["q_id"]=>
string(4) "2046"
["c_id"]=>
string(6) "a1"
["rank"]=>
int(1) "-1"
}
```

My code is as follow:

```
$result = mysql_query("Select * from table_1");     
while($cr = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
    $rr_id = $cr['batch_id'].$cr['seq_id'];
    $rid = '999'.$rr_id;
          $q_id = $cr['q_id'];
     foreach ($cr as $k => $v){
  if(preg_match('{^a\d+$}',$k)){
    $new_insert[] = array(
        'w_id'=>$rid,
        'q_id' =>$q_id,
        'c_id' =>$k,
        'rank'=>$v-1
);
     }
  }
```

However, the result of rank becomes

```
array(4) {
["w_id"]=>
string(5) "99911"
["q_id"]=>
string(4) "2046"
["c_id"]=>
string(6) "a1"
["rank"]=>
int(0)
}
```

Cannot show the value of rank

Any problem with my code??Can someone answer my question thank you very much

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`?

Comment: what is $cr initialized with?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense..

Comment: You have shown different result for your question and you are showing different result you get. Ask proper question.

Comment: I am so sorry that i made mistakes, i modified the question already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
$data = array_map(function ($v) {
    foreach($v as $k => &$x) {
        if (preg_match('{^a\d+$}', $k)) {
            $x = $x - 1;
        }
    }
    return $v;
}, $data);

print_r($data);
```

[Live Demo](http://eval.in/25146)

Comment: As the array may contains null , for example  [a1] => null , So i add one more condition   if($x == null){ $x = $x; }else {$x = $x-1;} .How ever if the value is 0 (e.g. [a1] => 0),then the ouput will become [a1] => 0 and didn't minus 1. if it is null how can I pass the null value, as I need to insert it into mysql later.


[Live Demo](http://eval.in/28296)

Comment: I am using php5.2.1 , it's not possible to use inline anonymous functions with array_map right?

Comment: That is pretty easy ... Just make it a function .. instead see Example 3 Here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('{^Item \d+$}',$k)
```

You've got wrong pattern inside preg_match (keys you are looking for are 'a1','a2'... not 'item 1', 'item 2'...), just use this one:

```
preg_match('{^a\d+$}',$k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use loop and pre decrementation

```
foreach($cr as $k=>&$v)
{
 --$v['a1'];--$v['a2'];--$v['a3'];--$v['a4'];--$v['a5'];
}

print_r($cr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use $cr  as your array.

```
$cr[] = array("batch_id"=>1, "seq_id"=>1, "q_id"=>'2046', "a1"=>1,"a2"=>1,"a3"=>1,"a4"=>1,"a5"=>1);

foreach($cr as $k=>&$v){
  $v['a1'] = $v['a1'] - 1;
  $v['a2'] = $v['a2'] - 1;
  $v['a3'] = $v['a3'] - 1;
  $v['a4'] = $v['a4'] - 1;
  $v['a5'] = $v['a5'] - 1;
}
print_r($cr);
```

Comment: `--$v['a1']` isn't easier? :)